# GPO WMI username filter not working over RDP

Tags: sql, active-directory, windows-server-2008, wmi, group-policy

I'm trying to write a WMI filter to prevent a GPO from applying to certain users

```
SELECT * from Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE NOT UserName LIKE 'domain\\user1_%' AND NOT UserName LIKE 'domain\\user2_%'
```

This works correctly if the user is logged onto the console but always returns false if the user is logged on via RDP.

Mark

EDIT:

There does seem to be a way to achieve this, it's described in method two of [this](http://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/01/quick-hit-find-currently-logged-on-users/) article. Though, I am unsure of how to construct the query using Win32_Process?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try querying from Win32_LogonSession? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394189(v=vs.85).aspx
Seems `LogonType` tells whether the user is logged on through RDP.

Comment: Unfortunately, that class doesn't include the users username which is vital to the query.